# How to ask for confirmation to delete checklist items?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have some dynamically generated checklist-items. When user deletes them, confirmation box should appear. How can i do that ?

```
protected void btndelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqlconn"].ConnectionString;
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn);
                con.Open();
            check:
                if (CheckBoxList1.SelectedItem != null)
                {
                    foreach (ListItem l in CheckBoxList1.Items)
                    {
                        if (l.Selected)
                        {
                            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Drop Table " + l, con);
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            Label4.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                            Label4.Text = " PaperSet Deleted successfully";
                            CheckBoxList1.Items.Remove(l);
                            papersetlist.Items.Remove(l);
                            Psetlist.Items.Remove(l);
                            goto check;
                        }
                    }
                }
                con.Close();

            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

This is delete button event code.

Comment: Have does you view looks like? Can you post some sample code what you have so far?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.confirm

Comment: I'm not sure what "when user deletes them" involves, but perhaps instead of a JavaScript solution you want to display an actual confirmation page? Same number of clicks for the user, but an extra layer of security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to write something like this

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
 CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" 
OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you certain you want to delete this item?');"> 
 </asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: please give a vote for my question -2 point is blocking me from asking more questions...

Comment: @rickevans - to complete task you just need to set this OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you certain you want to delete this item?');" on you delete button as i did on my link button